# filter list by one column using REST API

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, rest, filter

i want to filter a list by one spesific column. For exmple i want to see only when [City] = NYC.
I tried something likr this:

> _api/Lists/getbytitle('EmployeeInfo')/items?$filter=City eq NYC

But it's doesn't work for me.

thank

EDIT:

```
1.  $.ajax({  
2.    
3.          url: "/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('employeeInfo’)/items?$filter=City eq 'NYC'",
4.          headers: { Accept: "application/json;odata=verbose" },  
5.          method: GET,
6.          success: function (data) {  
7.                 Console.log("success");
8.              }    
9.          },error: function (data) {  
10.         alert("An error occurred. Please try again.");  
11. }  
12.     });  
13. }
```

Comment: here the issue is in the single quote replace 'employeeInfo’ with 'employeeInfo'

Answer (score 1):

Please try below code:

```
$.ajax({      
          url:  webUrl + "/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('employeeInfo’)/items?$filter=City eq 'NYC'",
          headers: { Accept: "application/json;odata=verbose" },  
          method: GET,
          success: function (data) {  

                 alert("success");
              }    
          },error: function (data) {  
                alert("error");  
            }  
     });  
 }
```

Hope it works for you.

Comment: hey thanks. i changed it, but still not working. i try to run it via WebPart/Javascript.

Comment: can you please give whole ajax call whichever used in your code?

Comment: please check updated answer

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the text `web` in the endpoint.

Also ensure the `City` column is the internal name and not display name.

`$filter` works on the internal name of the column

Try it as below:

```
/_api/web/Lists/getbytitle('EmployeeInfo')/items?$filter=City eq 'NYC'
```

Your code would be as below:

```
var webUrl = _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl;
//webUrl = url of the site where list is available
//var webUrl = "https://sitecollectionurl/subsite";  

$.ajax({      
          url:  webUrl + "/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('employeeInfo')/items?$filter=City eq 'NYC'",
          headers: { Accept: "application/json;odata=verbose" },  
          method: GET,
          success: function (data) {  
                 console.log(data);                  
                 console.log("success");
              }    
          },error: function (data) {  
                console.log("An error occurred. Please try again.");  
            }  
     });  
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try below :

```
_api/Lists/getbytitle('EmployeeInfo')/items?$filter=City eq 'NYC'
```